# VBA for combining multiple rows into one among multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I apologize for the long post, but I wanted to include as much information as possible. I was able to find some information online, but I need help altering. Here is an example of the data I need to combine below:

I need to combine this table:

| Part 1 | Part 2 | Full | Report | HRO Train | Time Manager | Attendee | Scheduled | Client Name | Client ID | Client Migrator | Supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/7/21 | 1/7/21 |  |  | 1/7/21 |  | Jane Doe | 2/2/21 | Jane Doe Inc | 123456789 | Sarah | Susan |
|  |  | 1/8/21 | 1/8/21 |  | 1/8/21 | Jane Doe | 2/2/21 | Jane Doe Inc | 123456789 | Sarah | Susan |
| 1/7/21 | 1/7/21 | 1/7/21 |  |  |  | John Dee | 3/1/21 | John Dee | 321654987 | Larry | Bob |
| 1/8/21 | 1/8/21 |  |  | 1/8/21 |  | John Dee | 3/1/21 | John Dee | 321654987 | Larry | Bob |

Into this table:

| Part 1 | Part 2 | Full | Report | HRO Train | Time Manager | Attendee | Scheduled | Client Name | Client ID | Client Migrator | Supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/7/21 | 1/7/21 | 1/8/21 | 1/8/21 | 1/7/21 | 1/8/21 | Jane Doe | 2/2/21 | Jane Doe Inc | 123456789 | Sarah | Susan |
| 1/7/21;1/8/21 | 1/7/21;1/8/21 | 1/7/21 |  | 1/8/21 |  | John Dee | 3/1/21 | John Dee | 321654987 | Larry | Bob |

I found [this thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-with-vba.887603/) for how to create a VBA that does this type of combining, but my data is a little different and I'm not sure how to alter the code to make it happen. I will copy-paste the code below:

```
'Dim 2 search cells
Dim BlankCell As Range
Dim IdCell As Range
'Find Last row and column
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'Set the area to consider
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lColumn))
'Select​ each blank cell in area
Rng.Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
'And replace it with appropriate value
For Each BlankCell In Selection
For Each IdCell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 1))
If (IdCell.Value = Cells(BlankCell.Row, 1).Value And Cells(IdCell.Row, BlankCell.Column) <> "") Then
BlankCell = Cells(IdCell.Row, BlankCell.Column).Value
End If
Next IdCell
Next BlankCell
'Then​ erase duplicate lines
Rng.Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lColumn)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), _
Header:=xlYes
```

With this VBA, it consolidates the rows down using Column A as the identifier to match. However, I need VBA to match Column G as the identifier, and I'm not sure where to edit to change the column. And for situations where I need to combine all dates with a ";" deliminator, I don't think this VBA addresses that situation. What more do I need to add to make that happen successfully? Thank you so much!